# jQuery check/uncheck radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have Woocommerce form where shipping depends on city. When you choose your city in dropbox it will update shipping price. Problem is when you want to change shipping from delivery to take away. Radio button is "permanently" checked. It just changes itself for one second and take it back.
[Here is streamable video](https://streamable.com/2fsrby)

```
jQuery('#billing_city').change(function(){ 
    var a = jQuery('.shipping__list_item:first-child input').prop("checked");
    var b = jQuery('.shipping__list_item:nth-child(2) input').prop("checked");

    jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
    jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
    if(a == true){
        jQuery('.shipping__list_item:first-child input').prop('checked', true);
    }else if(b == true){
        jQuery('.shipping__list_item:nth-child(2) input').prop('checked', true);
    }
    });
});
```

I tried to write something like that but it didnt help...

```
jQuery(".shipping__list_item:first-child input").click(function(){
    jQuery('.shipping__list_item:nth-child(2) input').prop('checked', false);
});
jQuery(".shipping__list_item:nth-child(2) input").click(function(){
   jQuery('.shipping__list_item:first-child input').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Many thanks for ideas...

Comment: don't nest one event handler inside another. I'm not quite sure what logic you are trying to implement here, but the result of what you've done is that, the handler function for `update_checkout` will trigger once for each time that the `#billing_city` change event has previously.

Comment: When i change #billing_city i need to update checkout and when checkout is updated i need to set the last position of radio button in shipping @RobinZigmond

Comment: *"Your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**."* Your code is not testable actually and you should include the custom checkout fields code.